# Changing Rectangular image from URL to Circular Bitmap shifts photo over?

Tags: android, facebook, bitmap

I have a url that I grab using the `Facebook API` here and I try to change this into a circular `Bitmap`. This works fine but my image actually appears to be off centered. Here is an example of what it looks like:

[image]

But I can't figure out what I am doing wrong with my code. Here is my code to transform the URL into a circular `Bitmap`:

```
public Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String userId) {
        try {
            URL imgUrl = new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/" + userId + "/picture?type=large");
            InputStream in = (InputStream) imgUrl.getContent();
            Bitmap  bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);

            Bitmap output;

            if (bitmap.getWidth() > bitmap.getHeight()) {
                output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getHeight(), bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            } else {
                output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getWidth(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            }

            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

            final int color = 0xff424242;
            final Paint paint = new Paint();
            final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());

            float r = 0;

            if (bitmap.getWidth() > bitmap.getHeight()) {
                r = bitmap.getHeight() / 2;
            } else {
                r = bitmap.getWidth() / 2;
            }

            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
            paint.setColor(color);
            canvas.drawCircle(r, r, r, paint);
            paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);
            return output;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Log exception
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You made mistake in this:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);
```

You copy not centered part of base image.

You should move source to middle of image. Working code:

```
public Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String userId) {
        try {
            URL imgUrl = new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/" + userId + "/picture?type=large");
            InputStream in = (InputStream) imgUrl.getContent();
            Bitmap  bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);

            Bitmap output;


            Rect srcRect;


            if (bitmap.getWidth() > bitmap.getHeight()) {
                output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getHeight(), bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                srcRect = new Rect((bitmap.getWidth()-bitmap.getHeight())/2, 0, bitmap.getWidth()+(bitmap.getWidth()-bitmap.getHeight())/2, bitmap.getHeight());


            } else {
                output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getWidth(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                srcRect = new Rect(0, (bitmap.getHeight()-bitmap.getWidth())/2, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight()+(bitmap.getHeight()-bitmap.getWidth())/2);

            }

            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

            final int color = 0xff424242;
            final Paint paint = new Paint();
            final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());

            float r = 0;

            if (bitmap.getWidth() > bitmap.getHeight()) {
                r = bitmap.getHeight() / 2;
            } else {
                r = bitmap.getWidth() / 2;
            }

            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
            paint.setColor(color);
            canvas.drawCircle(r, r, r, paint);
            paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, srcRect, rect, paint);
            return output;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Log exception
            return null;
        }
    }
```